# Export documents from sharepoint to another website

Tags: 2013, document, export, rest, json

I'm trying to get files and lists from my Sharepoint server showed on another website. 
How should I do to make a document viewable on the webpage, that is exported from SP2013? I also want to search for the files metadata on the website and be able to download the documents.

I've been Reading about REST and Json and think that is what I should use.

Would really appreciate someone helping me at the right direction.

Best regards, Blenni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second website is setup for anonymous access, then you will need to figure out how you are going to authenticate to the SharePoint site using an account that has access to the documents.  You could potentially run an export process on a scheduled basis, or fire it via a workflow when a document changes on the source side.  I've done this for pushing out content to anonymous sites before.

Using the REST services is your best bet for querying the files from other website since you can use that to connect to SharePoint from a remote system.

Here are some references for the REST services:

[REST Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)

[Querying Lists with REST](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/01/21/introduction-to-querying-lists-with-rest-and-listdata-svc-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the links and tip! Gave me a better view on how to use the REST interface. But are you able to "export" the document files content like word documents in the lists? And do I have to use Json for this? I could not find any good examples.

Comment: To export the documents you would typically make a connection to the document and then open a bitstream that can then be saved somewhere else.